# Parsing UIColor from NSKeyedArchiver: negative values

Tags: python, uicolor, nskeyedarchiver, nscolor

I'm trying to read a database, created by an iOS/macOS app, in Python. In one table is a column with binary data, which have been apparently archived with `NSKeyedArchiver`. My rows look like this:

```
{'$version': 100000, '$archiver': 'NSKeyedArchiver', '$top': {'root': UID(1)}, '$objects': ['$null', {'UIColorComponentCount': 4, 'UIGreen': 0.866697371006012, 'UIBlue': -0.2701350450515747, 'UIAlpha': 1.0, 'NSRGB': b'0.975 0.867 -0.27', '$class': UID(2), 'UIRed': 0.9749125838279724, 'NSColorSpace': 2}, {'$classname': 'UIColor', '$classes': ['UIColor', 'NSObject'], '$classhints': ['NSColor']}]}
{'$version': 100000, '$archiver': 'NSKeyedArchiver', '$top': {'root': UID(1)}, '$objects': ['$null', {'NSComponents': b'0.8875159454 0 0.06146364689 1', 'NSRGB': b'0.8483365774 0 0.05997940153\x00', 'NSColorSpace': 1, 'NSCustomColorSpace': UID(2), '$class': UID(5)}, {'NSID': 7, 'NSICC': UID(3), '$class': UID(4)}, '(replaced raw bytes)', {'$classname': 'NSColorSpace', '$classes': ['NSColorSpace', 'NSObject']}, {'$classname': 'NSColor', '$classes': ['NSColor', 'NSObject']}]}
{'$version': 100000, '$archiver': 'NSKeyedArchiver', '$top': {'root': UID(1)}, '$objects': ['$null', {'UIColorComponentCount': 4, 'UIGreen': 0.6479833126068115, 'UIBlue': -0.15340086817741394, 'UIAlpha': 1.0, 'NSRGB': b'0.163 0.648 -0.153', '$class': UID(2), 'UIRed': 0.16299211978912354, 'NSColorSpace': 2}, {'$classname': 'UIColor', '$classes': ['UIColor', 'NSObject'], '$classhints': ['NSColor']}]}
{'$version': 100000, '$archiver': 'NSKeyedArchiver', '$top': {'root': UID(1)}, '$objects': ['$null', {'NSRGB': b'0 0 0\x00', 'NSColorSpace': 2, '$class': UID(2)}, {'$classname': 'NSColor', '$classes': ['NSColor', 'NSObject']}]}
```

Unarchiving with `bpylist` allowed my to define custom classes for `UIColor` and `NSRGB`. Working with the 4 types of possible structures (see above) seems easy.

However, what me irritates is that there are negative RGB values in some rows. Apparently, this only happens with `UIColor` classes, possibly because the app uses `UIColorPicker`?

```
{'UIColorComponentCount': 4, 'UIGreen': -0.09628119319677353, 'UIBlue': -0.023068491369485855, 'UIAlpha': 1.0, 'NSRGB': b'0.746 -0.0963 -0.0231', '$class': UID(2), 'UIRed': 0.7462500929832458, 'NSColorSpace': 2}
{'UIColorComponentCount': 4, 'UIGreen': 0.6940679550170898, 'UIBlue': 0.7472937703132629, 'UIAlpha': 1.0, 'NSRGB': b'-0.252 0.694 0.747', '$class': UID(2), 'UIRed': -0.25186771154403687, 'NSColorSpace': 2}
{'UIColorComponentCount': 4, 'UIGreen': -0.13570761680603027, 'UIBlue': -0.06656593829393387, 'UIAlpha': 1.0, 'NSRGB': b'0.972 -0.136 -0.0666', '$class': UID(2), 'UIRed': 0.9720380902290344, 'NSColorSpace': 2}
```

How can RGB values be negative? Is something wrong with the parsing or am I missing something else here?